# How to utilise university resources when doing an independent research masters?

Tags: graduate-school, thesis, masters, advisor, research-proposal

I'm planning on undertaking a research masters in Earth Science or Geography within the UK.

During my undergraduate, there were many lectures, exams, courseworks/reports and workshops. I utilised my lecturers to ask questions about all of these things. Yet, my dissertation was very independent with minimal guidance or advice from lecturers (they mostly just nodded along).

**My research masters will only have a single thesis/dissertation to hand in (no exams, lectures or reports). How should I use my university to help me in this?** The obvious answer is lab equipment, but my thesis is most likely to be a desktop based study. Another answer is guidance from supervisors, but as I am required to come up with a thesis proposal before applying I will probably already have figured out much of what I need to do.

## Summary

If you're applying for a research masters in which there is only one piece of assessed work (your independent thesis), there is unlikely to be lab work (no need for uni equipment) and I must pre-decide a thesis proposal before applying (staff not available for guidance), how do I utilise the university to best help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your thesis advisor should be your principal channel of support. You say you'll already have your topic worked out, but that is far from having produced a finished thesis. The advisor's suggestions and references are intended to support you in producing graduate-level work; that person will know all about the relevant resources that might be available. Without the guidance of a professor you would be flying blind.